# Deploying Django with Apache/mod_wsgi (bogus ImportError)

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, importerror

I have spent two days trying to switch my project over from the dev server to production; however, I've hit a wall I can't get over.  mod_wsgi is installed, configured and I've tested that it works.  My django app works with runserver.

However, when I configure Apache to use my wsgi application, I am getting a 500 and can see in the Apache logs that the issue is an ImportError that was never there before.  I assumed it to be a PYTHONPATH issue, but I've verified with print statements that the contents of sys.path are the same when this import occurs as they should be.  Here's the error:

> `[error]File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.4.1-py2.6.egg/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 11`
>
> `[error]from django.db import utils`
>
> `[error]ImportError: cannot import name utils`

Now, why the psql backend can't even import utils from django.db despite it being on the PYTHONPATH is what's bugging me. A print statement of sys.path right before the import shows:

> `/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.4.1-py2.6.egg`

and even inserting

```
/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.4.1-py2.6.egg/django
/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.4.1-py2.6.egg/django/db
```

doesn't do any good.  I assume that to be redundant but am trying anything I can.

I've read all of the tutorials, docs, blog posts and stackoverflow posts about django/apache/mod_wsgi but whereas most people have trouble with importing their apps or settings, I've had no trouble with that but I can't get by this.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: The web server is out of file handles. Modify the startup script to use `ulimit` to increase the maximum.

Comment: Ignacio, could you explain this, please?  How did you determine that the import error is caused by a lack of file handles?

Comment: One piece of Django can't import another piece. This is not a normal situation, and very few things can explain it.

Comment: I see now, thanks, that makes a lot of sense.  I will give this a try.  Sorry, just to clarify, when you said "modify the startup script" are you referring to the apache startup or mod_wsgi?  A little more clarification would go a long way since I'm kind of a novice in this realm..

Comment: mod_wsgi is run as part of httpd, so there is only one startup script. I'm not sure where Bitnami places it though.

Comment: So the start up script for apache2 is /etc/init.d/apache2 which basically just calls apache2ctl.  I put "ulimit -n 999999" in the script and it did not solve my problem.  When I tried to restart apache with any higher of a number, it blocked me.  I also tried setting it with APACHE_ULIMIT_MAX_FILES in /etc/apache2/envvars and also directly in the script (which imports from envvars) for good measure and it had no effect.  Any ideas?  You mention "one piece of django" not being able to import from another.  Why did it work before when I was running the development server and not now?

Comment: May be the problem isn't it can't import `utils`. Like it could be a problem in `utils` module that try to import X module, and it fails. Or `utils` try to read some settings and they're invalid. May be there isn't enough rights for Apache to create/read a file (log/settings) and instead of IOError it fails while importing `utils`. May be you don't have some required Postgres binaries/packages installed. So I suggest investigate further, because it doesn't have to be 100% mod_wsgi problem.

Comment: Something is not right here, the error is misleading, cauz i just checked base.py file , the utils import is on line number 8 and on line number 11 there is -- django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2.operations import DatabaseOperations..

Comment: I attempted to resolve this problem by booting up a new instance and doing everything over (except for the coding).  This worked and then as soon as I killed the server and later started it up again, the problem returned.  Rebooting the machine solved the problem so now I just won't use "sudo apachectl stop" then "start" again.  Hardly a solution, so I won't mark it as one.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I still haven't seen one question where your suggestions of ulimit as being the problem has been valid. Why do you keep pushing that answer when there is no basis for it. All it does is waste peoples time as they chase it as a solution when it isn't. As explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238371/templatesyntaxerror-caught-importerror-while-rendering-cannot-import-name-util this problem has in the past been due to mismatches between the version of Python mod_wsgi is compiled for and Python version any Python virtual environment is constructed against.